# Check if wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel is currently scrolling

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm trying to use the ScrolledPanel in wx.lib.scrolledpanel, and i would like to check if the scrollbar of the ScrolledPanel is currently visible, so i can give my StaticText the correct wrap width. Because when the scrollbar is visible i need to remove another 10 pixels or so from the wrap width...

Anyone any idea how this is done?

Thanks!

Comment: I wasn't able to find anything in the documentation about this. You should ask on the wxPython mailing list. The devs there might have an idea.

Comment: I had a similar problem in my code. I just wrapped my text assuming the scrollbar would always be there. The scrollbar is narrow enough that it won't be too noticable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by getting the width of the parent widget inside the scrolledpanel, instead of the width of the scrolledpanel itself.

Sometimes the answer is so obvious :)